# creating tags for a script language for easy browsing in vim

Tags: vim, ctags, stata

I use ctags+Vim for a lot of my projects and I really like the ability to easily browse through large chunks of code quickly.

I am also using Stata, a statistical package, which has a script language. Even though you can have routines in the code, its code tends to be series of commands that perform data and statistics operations. And the code files can be very long. So I always find myself in need of a way to browse it efficiently.

Since I use Vim, I can use marks. But I was wondering if I could use ctags to do this. That is, I want to create a tag marker which (1) won't cause a problem when I run the script (2) easy to introduce to ctags.

Because it is supposed to not break the script, it needs to be a comment. In Stata, comment lines start with `*` and flow comments can be made by `/* ..... */`.

It would be great, for example, have sections in the code, marked by comments:

```
* Section: Data
```

And ctags picks up "Data Manipulation" as the tag. So I can see a list of sections and jump to them easily without the needs for creating marks.

Is there anyway to do this? I'd appreciate any comments.

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to generate a tags database for your Stata files. The format is simple, see `:help tags-file-format`. The default tags program, *Exuberant Ctags* can be [extended with regular expressions](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/EXTENDING.html) (`--langmap`, `--regex`); that probably only yields an approximate parsing for complex languages, but it should suffice for custom section marks; maybe you could even directly extract interesting language keywords.

Comment: I need to figure out how to do this, in an operational way.  I never got around learning regular expressions. If I do, I will write the solution up here.

Comment: You won't get the full benefits of Vim without at least a basic knowledge of regular expressions, anyway! And it's such a proven universal concept that every IT professional should know them. Be aware that there are slight differences between Vim and other tools like ctags or Perl.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I guess the problem is I am not really an IT professional but a graduate student of economics who is doing a lot of number crunching. But as you said, a little bit of knowledge of regular expressions seem to go a long way.